# Class template for removing constness, volatileness and referenceness fails to compile after Boost/compiler update

Tags: c++, templates, boost, type-traits

I recently updated the version of Boost I use from 1.59 to 1.68. Additionally, I also updated the version of Visual Studio I use from 2015 to 2017. After these changes, my class template below, which is used to remove constness, volatileness and referenceness, fails to compile.

```cpp
// Class for removing constness, volatileness and referenceness
template<typename T>
struct Cleaner
{
    // Part1: Remove referenceness and constness at the highest level
    typedef  
        typename boost::remove_cv< 
            typename  boost::remove_reference<typename T>::type 
        >::type 
        CleanPart1;

    // Part2: If pointer, remove the const under the pointer and re-add the pointer
    typedef typename 
        typename boost::mpl::if_c< !boost::is_pointer< CleanPart1 >::value, 
            typename CleanPart1,
            typename boost::add_pointer< 
                typename boost::remove_cv< 
                    typename boost::remove_pointer<CleanPart1>::type
                >::type
            >::type
        >::type 
        CleanPart2;

    // Store final clean type
    typedef CleanPart2 Type;
};
```

Said class template could be used as follows in a function template that receives a template parameter `T`:

```cpp
typedef typename Cleaner<T>::Type CleanT;
```

The compilation errors Visual Studio is displaying are quite cryptic:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Cleaner<T>'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C3646: 'Type': unknown override specifier
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I have been studying this code for quite a while, and I can't find the reason why it fails to compile. Everything looks correct to me. Does anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: I've gotten numerous errors trying to compile this code, none of which match what you report. Could you provide something that can be copied and pasted as-is (c.f. [mcve])?

Comment: Dear JaMiT, thanks for your suggestion! In the process of setting up the minimal reproducible example, I discovered that this include was required: `#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>`. For some reason it wasn't needed in Boost 1.59.0, but in 1.68.0 it is needed. Thank you!